# How to return custom JSON objects in an ASP.NET Framework web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a small web API for a course android application project. I made a `Get` method that returns a list of all users and all their attributes (which I don't need but it's ok for now since I am only testing on localhost).

Problem starts when I try to implement the `Get` method for just 1 user. I access `/api/user?username=admin` and it returns what I tell it to return but it doesn't return it in the JSON format unless I get the entire object (which is a bad idea because what if I want to remove the password from the response?)

This is how the raw JSON file for `/api/user` looks like:

the Users table is 
`USERNAME (string) : EMAIL (string) : PASSWORD (string) : UTYPE (Byte)`

```
[{"USERNAME":"admin","EMAIL":"admin@domain","PASSWORD":"p","UTYPE":2},{"USERNAME":"merchTest","EMAIL":"merchTest@merch.com","PASSWORD":"bezzo","UTYPE":1},{"USERNAME":"onlineTestConsumer","EMAIL":"onlineTestConsumer@bezzo.com","PASSWORD":"bezzo","UTYPE":2},{"USERNAME":"zz","EMAIL":"zzz@live.com","PASSWORD":"zzzz","UTYPE":2}]
```

Which is correct.

But this is how the raw JSON file for `/api/user?username=admin` looks like

```
"p"
```

Which is obviously not right.

Here's my code for `UserController.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using UserDataAccess;

namespace OkBoomerREST_API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/user")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<USER> Get()
        {
            using (DB_A5061A_okboomerEntities users = new DB_A5061A_okboomerEntities())
            {
                return users.USERs.ToList();
            }    
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(String username)
        {
            using (DB_A5061A_okboomerEntities users = new DB_A5061A_okboomerEntities())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(users.USERs.Where(u => u.USERNAME == username).ToList()[0].PASSWORD)
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want: The 2nd `Get` method to return a proper JSON object but **without** the password field (Basically, `{"USERNAME":"admin","EMAIL":"admin@domain","UTYPE:2}`). How can I do that?

I am very new to anything related to web and I am doing this just to be doing my project right (but I don't have to so this isn't a 'homework question') so I'd appreciate if answers were dumbed down to my level hahaha. I am sorry if it's a kind of stupid question but I have been staring at this for 3 hours now and all the answers I find online are ASP.NET Core so I don't really know what to do here.

Comment: Content = new StringContent(users.USERs.Where(u => u.USERNAME == username).ToList()[0].PASSWORD) << that line looks like you are setting the content to what the Password is - meaning you're getting the password as the response.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky oh I know! I can omit the password but that's not my issue, my issue is that the output isn't in a JSON format and is just plain text (I think?) and I want to return a JSON object with all the other attributes EXCEPT the password. If it was `...[0].USERNAME` I'd still have the same problem.

Comment: passwords in clear ... in 2020 almost .... do we never learn?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu I am a 3rd year student and this is the first time I have ever dealt with web/android dev so I am not really knowledgeable about security. I know passwords shouldn't be stored in plain text but it's a software engineering course project so I thought it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new anonymous object

```
`var UserWithoutPassword = users.USERs
           .Where(u => u.USERNAME == username).Select(x => new
                           {
                                P1 = table.Prop1,
                                P2 = table.Prop2
                           }).ToList();
Content = new StringContent(users.USERs.Where(u => u.USERNAME == username).ToList()`
```

Try something like this.

Another option, more lazy , go through the list and replace password with ''

Comment: I am getting an error at the `.Select()` because `Select` isn't overloaded to take 0 arguments. Am I missing something?

Comment: ups , forgot the select part